# Vanitygen regular expression match

Tags: bitcoind, vanitygen

Using regular expression match instead of prefix, is there a way to add a difficulty and probability check? Seems to only report keys/s and total keys tested.

Comment: I don't think vanitygen does much beyond generating addresses and checking them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple algorithm to estimate the difficulty. Doing that requires you to first determine the [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) of the [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29) between the [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_Language) expressed by the input regular expression, and the set of all valid public keys.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the output is random:

How many randomly generated texts (in the base58 dictionary that *coin addresses use) are going to match my regex?

The output is not exactly random, so that's a shame, but it will give you a good enough indication.

Remember they call it vanity addresses for a good reason! It's all kind of vain.